# Matching Multiple Lists

Tags: prolog

I can write a predicate that is satisfied when two lists are equal e.g. equal([2,3],[2,3]) would be true and equal([2,3],[4,5]). would be false.

However, what if I want to have a list and try and match it with any list in a list of lists e.g. match([2,3],[[5,6],[4,6,2],[2,3]]). would be true because of the last list in the list of lists but match([2,3],[[3,4],[4,2,1]]). would be false because [2,3] doesn't match anything in the list of lists.

I'm thinking maybe we might need nested recursion here?  Any idea how you do this?  The problem I'm trying to solve is much larger but just being able to do this would allow me to solve the whole problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursive navigation of a Prolog list is usually achieved by means of a couple of clauses: the first is the condition by which the recursion is stopped and a result is returned; the second contains the recursive call. To this aim, in each clause's head the list on which the recursion has to be performed is typically broken in two parts, isolating the first element (known as head) from the rest of the list (known as tail), such as in the following:

```
p(Element, [Head | Tail]) :- % ...
```

In that recursive clause, you process `Head` and, depending on the result, you proceed to call your predicate passing `Tail` as second argument, thus actually navigating the whole list one element at a time.

In writing such a predicate, you may cut (using `!`) alternative solutions (that sometimes produce only failures) when you find the result you were looking for, e.g. in your case, once you find a match between the first list and an element in the second list, you don't need to proceed further, so any possibly open branch in the demonstration tree should be pruned.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Giulio.  However, I know about recursion, base cases, recursive cases, heads, tails, cuts, matching heads etc.  My issue is that I have something like this: match( [2,3], [[4,5],[7,8],[2,3]] ). and I want to know how you match my [2,3] with the nested list i.e. I'm confused about how you match a whole list with a single list in a list of lists.  I will keep working on this and post any answers of progress I make.  Any advice about this?  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I was imagining things were more complicated because of the nested list but something as simple as this actually works:

```
 match( Search, [H|_] ) :-
    Search = H, !.
match( Search, [H|T] ) :-
    Search \= H,
    match( Search, T ).
```

Giulio, your answer was very helpful so thanks :).

Comment: I was just about to hint you about the first of your clauses after reading your comment to my answer, but I see you solved it yourself. Nice. Anyway, as a bonus: that first clause can be written as `match(Search, [Search|_]) :- !.` directly, exploiting the underlying unification performed by Prolog while searching for compatible clauses.